# Keep hidden taskbar in background of maximized windows

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

On earlier versions of Windows (up to 7, I believe) it was possible to configure the taskbar to stay in the background of maximized windows, in addition to the 'hide' option. Only pressing the windows key would bring the taskbar up to the foreground.

Is there a way to get the taskbar to behave this way in Windows 10? There doesn't seem to be an official option anymore. Perhaps there is some registry hack or a 3rd-party app? Google didn't turn up anything current.

For context: A lot of the programs I use have buttons near the bottom the window and it's so easy to overshoot and touch the bottom of the screen, bringing up the taskbar, which then covers the button I wanted to press. Annoying.

People have asked this question here before over the years, but seemingly never got the answer they (and I) were looking for. I wonder why more people aren't bovered by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By sheer coincidence (while looking for something unrelated), I just found '7+ Taskbar Tweaker' (https://tweaker.rammichael.com/), a freeware tool to customize the taskbar. Despite the name, the tool also works with Windows 10. Among its 'Advanced Options' there is a 'disable_topmost' setting that does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 does automatically hides the taskbar when you open a window in
*full screen mode*.

However, full-screen window mode is quite different from maximized window mode
(you can see the title bar in maximized window mode by default),
which Windows does not detect.

To hide the taskbar also for maximized windows needs a third-party application.
One such is
[SmartTaskbar](https://github.com/ChanpleCai/SmartTaskbar),
also available from the
[Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/smarttaskbar/9pjm69mps6t9?activetab=pivot%3aoverviewtab).

---

Since SmartTaskbar is not a good solution, here is DIY solution that uses
the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following script will set the desktop area to the whole screen
when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> is pressed, in effect eliminating
the taskbar. To undo press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>.
Change the two `bottom` values to the requested height of the screen
in pixels in your case.

> ```
> ^F9::
> bottom = 2160      ; Screen-Resolution: 3840 * 2160 --> FullScreen
> WinHide, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
> WinHide, Start ahk_class Button
> SetWorkArea(left,top,right,bottom)
> Return
> ^F10::
> bottom = 2085      ; FullScreen - TaskbarHeight --> Normal
> WinShow, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
> WinShow, Start ahk_class Button
> SetWorkArea(left,top,right,bottom)
> Return
> SetWorkArea(left,top,right,bottom) {
> VarSetCapacity(area, 16)
>  DllCall("ntoskrnl.exe\RtlFillMemoryUlong", UInt,&area + 0, UInt,4, UInt,left)
>  DllCall("ntoskrnl.exe\RtlFillMemoryUlong", UInt,&area + 4, UInt,4, UInt,top)
>  DllCall("ntoskrnl.exe\RtlFillMemoryUlong", UInt,&area + 8, UInt,4, UInt,right)
>  DllCall("ntoskrnl.exe\RtlFillMemoryUlong", UInt,&area + 12,UInt,4, UInt,bottom)
>  DllCall("SystemParametersInfo", UInt,0x2F, UInt,0, UInt,&area, UInt,0) ; SPI_SETWORKAREA
> }
> ```

[source](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/42005-remove-taskbar/)

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test.
You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the traybar
and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Comment: SmartTaskbar unfortunately doesn't seem to provide the functionality I'm after. It only appers to switch the 'hide automatically' option on/off depending on whether there is a maximized window.

Comment: Interesting. How could this workaround be adapted for a multi-display environment? Does SetWorkArea affect the desktop area as a whole and only those two height values need to be customized?

Comment: With multiple display monitors, the work area rectangle points to the monitor that contains the specified rectangle, meaning in the entire extended desktop. You should look at the desktop as a single space where the screen areas are stuck together each in its position, so that the pixels are summed-up on all axes. You should in this case specify the variables left, right & top.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to AutoHotkey! While I found a different solution for my issue, this seems to be a powerful tool and I already have something else in mind for it.